# Java - The method descendingIterator() is undefined for the type List<Object>

Tags: java, list, compiler-errors, linked-list, iterator

My code is

```
List<Object> listOld = new LinkedList<Object>();
listOld.add("Hello");
listOld.add(1000);
listOld.add(25);
listOld.add(85.9);
Iterator x = listOld.descendingIterator();
```

Error is:

> Tester.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
> Iterator x = listOld.descendingIterator();
> ^
> symbol:   method descendingIterator()
> location: variable listOld of type List
> 1 error

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: A `List` doesn't have a descending iterator, only a `LinkedList` does. So you need to declare your type to specifically be a `LinkedList` if you want to access those specific members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method  `Iterator<E> descendingIterator()` is declared in the interace `java.util.Deque<E> extends Queue<E>`. `LinkedList` is an implementation of `Deque`, and `List` interface does not extend `Deque`.

So if you change your code to the following, it should work.

```
LinkedList<Object> listOld = new LinkedList<Object>();
Iterator x = listOld.descendingIterator();
```